# Make only uses VPATH on the second run?

Tags: c, assembly, makefile

I am trying to compile and assemble, then link, some source files. As far as I can tell, it doesn't tell the linker to use the path in VPATH until I run it the second time.
Here's the Makefile:

```
#Makefile for SWS ARMKern

CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
LD=arm-linux-gnueabi-ld
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu11 -ffreestanding -march=armv6 -msoft-float -fPIC -mapcs-frame
LDFLAGS=-N -Ttext=0x10000
HWDEF=versatilepb #The set of hardware quirks to use.

#Paths
VPATH=src/:obj/
CINC=-Isrc/include/

kernel.elf: bootstrap.o kernel.o

.PHONY: clean test

clean:
    rm -f obj/*.o elf/*.elf

test:
    qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -nographic -soundhw none -kernel elf/kernel.elf

.SUFFIXES: .s .o .c .elf

.o.elf:
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o elf/$@ $^

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINC) -DHWCLASS=$(HWDEF) -o obj/$@ -c $^

.s.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINC) -DHWCLASS=$(HWDEF) -o obj/$@ -c $^
```

This is what happens:

```
> ls
elf  isosrc  Makefile  Makefile~  obj  README.md  README.md~  src
> make kernel.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu11 -ffreestanding -march=armv6 -msoft-float -fPIC -mapcs-frame -Isrc/include/ -DHWCLASS=versatilepb  -o obj/kernel.o -c src/kernel.c
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu11 -ffreestanding -march=armv6 -msoft-float -fPIC -mapcs-frame -Isrc/include/ -DHWCLASS=versatilepb  -o obj/bootstrap.o -c src/bootstrap.s
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -N -Ttext=0x10000 -o elf/kernel.elf kernel.o bootstrap.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld: cannot find kernel.o: No such file or directory
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld: cannot find bootstrap.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'kernel.elf' failed
make: *** [kernel.elf] Error 1
> make kernel.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -N -Ttext=0x10000 -o elf/kernel.elf obj/kernel.o obj/bootstrap.o
```

I'm sure it's just an issue with my Makefile, but I'm stumped. How do I make sure that the linker uses the VPATH paths? Or even just force it to look in obj/

Thanks!

Comment: .SUFFIXES is obsolete and it defines the order of handling of files.  In the /SUFFIXES statement, it is saying to handle .o files before .c files.  That will be a problem.  The default .SUFFIXES in make properly lists all the file name endings, so the .SUFFIXES should not be in the 'local' makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VPATH` is the path to search for *sources*, not targets, so only files that exist on the `VPATH` when make starts are relevant.  Since the first time you run make, none of your .o files exist, make cannot find them.  You're also lying to make with your suffix rules -- a rule like `.c.o:` tells make "Here's how to make a `.o` file in the current directory from a `.c` file", but then the action makes the file in the `obj` subdirectory.

If you're using GNU make or BSD make, you can use pattern rules that include the directories:

```
elf/%.elf: obj/%.o:
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

obj/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINC) -DHWCLASS=$(HWDEF) -o $@ -c $^

obj/%.o: %.s
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINC) -DHWCLASS=$(HWDEF) -o $@ -c $^
```

Pattern rules completely subsume all uses of suffix rules -- with GNU or BSD make you should *never* use suffix rules, and use pattern rules instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
kernel.elf: bootstrap.o kernel.o
```

Try

```
kernel.elf: obj/bootstrap.o obj/kernel.o
```

Comment: In the Makefile I'm using `$^` to specify the input files so I can't do that. (look at recipie .o.elf) I tried `obj/$^` but that results in `obj/bootstrap.o kernel.o` which still doesn't work.

Comment: If it's reading VPATH only on the second run, you can also try " VPATH := "  instead of just " VPATH= "

Comment: That doesn't work. I have the same error still. There are no variables in my VPATH anyway, it's just `src/:obj/`

Comment: I think you may be encountering this problem: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by changing my `.o.elf` rule to:

```
.o.elf:
    cd obj/ && \
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o ../elf/$@ $^
```

i.e. changing directory into the /obj directory. This is a stupid hack and I don't like it, but it works.